# How can I get the regex equivalent if the expression are in separate lines?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
Datum Kundnummer Sida
2018-10-12 196979 1 /2
```

The two strings above are in separate lines

What is the regex equivalent so that I get the following output?

```
Datum 2018-10-12
Kundnummer 196979
```

The above two are separate outputs

I want the output such that it works for all dates in datum and all numbers in Kundnummer.

I tried `Datum\s([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))`
and `Kundnummer\s(\d+)`.

Comment: If all your data contains is those two lines and the content of the first line is constant, don't bother matching the first line at all. Match something that conforms to the format of the second line and extracts the relevant parts, like `([12]\d{3}-0[1-9]|1[0-2]-0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\s(\d+)` and replace by `Datum \1\nKundnummer \2`

Comment: Oh and the big problem with the regex you tried is that while it would perfectly match the format of your expected output, what you need it to match is the format of your input.

Comment: How can I replace it..Can you just explain that!

Comment: Sorry, I don't do much python. Look into the "re" module's documentation.

Comment: Why would you use regex for this? It seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the data in the first line is always the same, so I'd ignore it.

To get the "Datum" and "Kundennummer" entries from the second line, use `(?P<datum>\d{4}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2})\s(?P<kundennummer>\d+?).*`.

As @PyHunterMan explained, you could also just split the string at the whitespaces. That would probably be the easier way.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you wage on time figuring this out when you can do it in a simple lines of code without regex.

```
_input = "Datum Kundnummer Sida\n2018-10-12 196979 1 /2"
lines = _input.split('\n')
old_line_one, old_line_two = lines[0].split(), lines[1].split()
new_line_one = f'{old_line_one[0]} {old_line_two[0]}'
new_line_two = f'{old_line_one[1]} {old_line_two[1]}'
print(f'{new_line_one}\n{new_line_two}')
```

Comment: I agree. regex is overkill for this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something like this:

```
reobj = re.compile(r"(?P<datum>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})\s+(?P<kundnummer>\d+)")
match = reobj.search(input)
if match:
    result1 = match.group("datum")
    result2 = match.group("kundnummer")
```